# in PHP how to calculate full uncompressed public key from a short 02/03 pubkey?

Tags: public-key, php

in PHP how do i create the full public key from a compressed one?

my test key is
026a04ab98d9e4774ad806e302dddeb63bea16b5cb5f223ee77478e861bb583eb3

and the uncompressed one is 
6a04ab98d9e4774ad806e302dddeb63bea16b5cb5f223ee77478e861bb583eb3
36b6fbcb60b5b3d4f1551ac45e5ffc4936466e7d98f6c7c0ec736539f74691a6

can this be done via openssl?

thanks for any helpful answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using MDANTER's great library i managed it to work.
if anyone needs it in the future.

```
use Elliptic\EC;
$ec = new EC('secp256k1');
$pub="026a04ab98d9e4774ad806e302dddeb63bea16b5cb5f223ee77478e861bb583eb3";
$key = $ec->keyFromPublic($pub, 'hex');
print_r($key);
```